# Awk match and for loop requirement

Tags: awk

I'm struggling to understand what I'm doing wrong here. The output gets repeated the number of times a disk is seen:

```
Parted -l |
awk -F '[ :] '/^Disk \//{print $2}' |
while read LINE; do
    blkid $LINE1 |
    awk -F ' ' '{
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            print $i;
            if($i ~ /UUID*/) {
                print $i;
                exit
            }
        }
    }';
done
```

If I have three disks in my system e.g. /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1

Input to above set of commands:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="/" UUID="feg45687-576466-676445-6536-7534-5784326797fbfg" TYPE="ext4"
```

Current output from above commands:

```
UUID="feg45687-576466-676445-6536-7534-5784326797fbfg"
UUID="tug45687-576466-676445-6536-7534-68546df" 
UUID="feg45687-576466-676445-6536-7534-9908536lk"

UUID="feg45687-576466-676445-6536-7534-5784326797fbfg"
UUID="tug45687-576466-676445-6536-7534-68546df" 
UUID="feg45687-576466-676445-6536-7534-9908536lk"

UUID="feg45687-576466-676445-6536-7534-5784326797fbfg"
UUID="tug45687-576466-676445-6536-7534-68546df" 
UUID="feg45687-576466-676445-6536-7534-9908536lk"
```

What is expected output:

```
UUID="feg45687-576466-676445-6536-7534-5784326797fbfg"
UUID="tug45687-576466-676445-6536-7534-68546df" 
UUID="feg45687-576466-676445-6536-7534-9908536lk"
```

So if I have three disks i get the same UUID line repeated three times.

Any way of moving to the next LINE without repeating?

Comment: better provide some input and desired output, otherwise it is a bit of "why is this code [not] working?"

Comment: would be good to clean the code of references of `blkid` and give a working example. Otherwise it is a bit hard to assist you in this.

Comment: Sorry not understanding what you mean. Clean what precisely?

Comment: in the first code you posted, there is a reference to `blkid` --> ` ... | while read LINE; do blkid ...`. This is, to me, superfluous and makes it more complicated to run the command locally to try to find a better solution

Comment: Since the posted sample input (presumably the output of `Parted -l`) `/dev/sda1: LABEL="/" UUID="feg45687-576466-676445-6536-7534-5784326797fbfg" TYPE="ext4"` does not start with `/^Disk \/` as required by the first awk script, the above CANNOT produce the output you say it does. Please edit the question to produce precise, testable sample input and expected output and as @fedorqui says either get rid of `bldik` or show it's intermediate output given the posted sample input so we can test a potential solution against your input/output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem (or, at least, one of your problems) is probably in the lines:

```
while read LINE; do
    blkid $LINE1 |
```

You read into `$LINE`, but you reference `$LINE1`, an unrelated and probably uninitialized variable, which probably leads `blkid` to list all devices each time.

Fix: choose one name or the other — don't use both.

Comment: You are a star!! Thank you.